# BDD and UI Testing

Tags: testing, user-interface, bdd

Here's a question...

We have a WPF MVVM application using IronRuby. We use the DevExpress dock manager. We have cucumber tests (getting it to work on IronRuby was our team lead's via dolorosa)

Part of our requirements is allowing the user to save the layout of their screen. What's a good way to wrap BDD tests around this?

The layout is saved when the user closes the app.

Here is my first idea.

1. Have cucumber open the app.
2. Have cucumber use bewildr and/or white to move stuff about. 
   (It's hard to simulate a user moving the layout about.)
3. Take a screenshot or something.
4. Close the app.
5. Open the app again.
6. Take a screenshot or something.
7. Compare the screenshots or something

See, while that would work, I think its a convoluted way to get things done. I was hoping somebody here can give me a suggestion on what "something" in the above steps could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White is based on UI Automation, and if it doesn't support docking and bounding rectangles you can always dig into the UI Automation patterns and use those. Try using `DockingPattern` and `BoundingRectangleProperty` on the panels you're interested in. That should allow you to record where they're docked and what size they are, at least.

Also remember that you don't need to write automated scenarios for *everything*. Aesthetic and usability concerns are often better tested manually, since they have no benefit if the users don't like them, regardless of what the automated tests believe. The scenarios are there to ensure a common understanding - through the conversations they drive - and to help keep things easy to change - by providing documentation and a safety net. If you're never going to change your docking mechanism (because it's a 3rd party app) then just test it manually and leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Bewildr elements will have 'width' and 'height' methods available in the next release (a few days from now - the code's checked in and working). I guess you could use them to get the size of the element to see if it remains the same across app-restarts. You could also use the 'clickable_point' method to tell whether the clickable point of the element (usually the center point) moves across app-restarts - a bit hacky but it would work...